# Add transparent border around an Image

Tags: html, gd

I am using phpThumb to overlay a couple of images, this makes use of the GD library. In order for this function to work the images been to be the same size. So when a user uploads an image I have to validate the size. And finally for it to display correctly I need to add a transparent border around the image so the underlaying image is the same size.

So I can't use a CSS approach. I don't know if there is some other GD call that can do this but the web site is currently down (http://www.libgd.org/).

What approach would you recommend to add the transparent border?

Comment: I think you can use a lot more easier approach. With phpthumb you change the image size. And I don't understand why exactly you need the border. can you add some code maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Margin in css works like a transparent border. But for your problem there are better ways:

First of all if you are using phpThumb you can resize images authomatically, so no need to validate image size:

```
<?php

    require_once 'path/to/ThumbLib.inc.php';

    try
    {
         $thumb = PhpThumbFactory::create('/path/to/image.jpg');
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        // handle error here however you'd like
    }
    $thumb->resize(100, 100);
    $thumb->show();
?>
```

You can find [here](https://github.com/masterexploder/PHPThumb/wiki/Basic-Usage) more details.

I didn't understand exactly why you need a border. But if you want to use overlays on your image no need to add a border to the image to fit the overlay. If you need an overlay on your image you can do something like this:

```
 <div class="container">
   <img src="path to your image" />
   <span class="overlay"></span>
 </div>
```

and apply some style:

```
.container{ // the same size as your image
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

.overlay{
   position: absolute;
   top:0;
   left: 0;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   background: ...
   ...
}
```

Comment: The reason I want the transparent border is that I am using phpThumb to overlay a frame round the picture. So the picture has to be resized to the inside of the frame. If the underlying image and the frame are not the same size phpThumb will distort one of the images, not unreasonably. So once I have the picture the right size for the inside of the frame I then want to out a transparent bored around it so the frame and the picture are the same size. Does that explain it?

Comment: Well, not really, I need to see some code to understand what is the problem